# How to SUM distinct out of of GROUP BY that have duplicates

Tags: sql, database, reporting, data-warehouse

I am calculating average number of orders per person within four groups, and I have the following SQL

```
SELECT      TO_DATE(ORDER_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific','YYYY-MM-DD'),
            GROUP_P,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN ORDER_TIME IS NOT null
                       THEN ORDER_ID END) AS Numerator,
            COUNT(DISTINCT
                  CASE WHEN ORDER_TIME IS NOT null
                       THEN PERSON_ID END) AS Denominator
FROM        ORDER_TAB 
WHERE       TO_DATE(ORDER_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific','YYYY-MM-DD')
BETWEEN     DATEADD( day, -1, current_Date) AND current_Date
GROUP BY    1, 2
```

My result looks like this

```
to_date     group_p    numerator   denominator
2021-06-01  A          28          20
2021-06-01  B          5           5
2021-06-01  C          1577        1025
2021-06-01  D          1010        765
```

Because one `person_id` can be in different groups, if I sum up from the above table, I wouldn't have the accurate denominator value due to potential duplicates. In my below code, I removed the `group by`, and the `numerator` sums up the same, but the `denominator` is getting less.

```
SELECT      TO_DATE(ORDER_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific','YYYY-MM-DD'),

            COUNT(CASE WHEN ORDER_TIME IS NOT null
                       THEN ORDER_ID END) AS Numerator,
            COUNT(DISTINCT
                  CASE WHEN ORDER_TIME IS NOT null
                       THEN PERSON_ID END) AS Denominator
FROM        ORDER_TAB 
WHERE       TO_DATE(ORDER_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific','YYYY-MM-DD')
BETWEEN     DATEADD( day, -1, current_Date) AND current_Date
GROUP BY    1
```

```
to_date     numerator   denominator
2021-06-01  2620        1699
```

Because of our reporting requirement, I must keep the output in the way that showed with `group_p` column.

What is the best way to use the accurate `1699` when summing up from the output?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of the logic you want, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: If a person is present in one multiple group in which group  he/she should be counted? And is numerator value correct it first output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query will count person_id once (first group in ascending order) for Denominator column. I have used row_number() window ranking function with common table expression for that.

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT      GROUP_P,
                ORDER_TIME,
                row_number()over(partition by person_id order by group_p) rnk            
    FROM        ORDER_TAB 
    WHERE       TO_DATE(ORDER_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific','YYYY-MM-DD')
    BETWEEN     DATEADD( day, -1, current_Date) AND current_Date
)
select    TO_DATE(ORDER_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific','YYYY-MM-DD'),
          GROUP_P,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN ORDER_TIME IS NOT null
                     THEN ORDER_ID END) AS Numerator,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN ORDER_TIME IS NOT null and rnk=1
                     THEN PERSON_ID END) AS Denominator
from cte
```